# Error uploading photo from iOS to server

Tags: php, ios, apache, http

I am having an error uploading a photo from my iOS application to my web server.

I was wondering if anybody knows where the problem may be, and how I can approach fixing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the error message:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 webmaster@namehere.ca to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Here is the iOS code:

```
- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 90);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://website.ca/uploadPhoto.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
}
```

And Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$ran = rand () ;

$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir .$ran.$file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "Uploaded";
}
?>
```

Comment: do a print_r($_FILES); and add it here.

Comment: What error gives you?

Comment: I should recommend using AFNetworking its simpler wrapper to do this stuff.. Because your PHP code seems to be right. the code problem should be on your Objective-C code when posting the binary data transmission

Answer (score 0):

the image is recieved in $_POST['userfile'] instead of $_Files['userfile']... use following code

```
 <?php


$image = $_POST['userfile'];
$image = str_replace("<","",$image);
$image = str_replace(">","",$image);
$image = str_replace(" ","",$image);
$image = pack("H*", $image);
$filename = "img/image.png";
$f = fopen($filename,'wb');
fwrite($f, $image);
fclose($f);



?>
```